# Unable to remove CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, cashapelayer

I have a total of 21 lines drawn across the screen for a measurement tool. The lines are drawn as a layer on UIViewController.view. I am attempting to remove the lines as follows. The NSLog statement confirms that I am getting all 21 CAShapeLayers that I am looking for.

```
CAShapeLayer* layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc]init];
    for (UIView *subview in viewsToRemove){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]]){
            count++;
            NSLog(@"%d: %@", count, subview);
            [layerArray addObject:layer];
        }
    }
    for(CAShapeLayer *l in layerArray){
        [l removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
```

Any help getting these lines removed would be greatly appreciated.

I don't think it's necessary but if you want to see the code to draw the lines here it is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++){
    CAShapeLayer *lineShape = nil;
    CGMutablePathRef linePath = nil;
    linePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    lineShape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    if(i == 0 || i == 20 || i == 10 || i == 3 || i == 17)
        lineShape.lineWidth = 4.0f;
    else
        lineShape.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    lineShape.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
    if( i == 0 || i == 20)
        lineShape.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    else if(i == 3 || i == 17)
        lineShape.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
    else if (i == 10)
        lineShape.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
    else
        lineShape.strokeColor = [[UIColor grayColor]CGColor];

    x += xIncrement;  y = 5;


    int toY = screenHeight - self.toolBar.frame.size.height - 10;
    CGPathMoveToPoint(linePath, NULL, x, y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, NULL, x, toY);
    lineShape.path = linePath;
    CGPathRelease(linePath);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:lineShape];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no sense:

```
CAShapeLayer* layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc]init];
for (UIView *subview in viewsToRemove){
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]]){
        count++;
        NSLog(@"%d: %@", count, subview);
        [layerArray addObject:layer];
    }
}
for(CAShapeLayer *l in layerArray){
    [l removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

You are *creating a completely new* CAShapeLayer and then adding *that same CAShapeLayer* (namely your `layer` object) over and over to the `layerArray`. It is never *in* the interface, it never *has* a superlayer, and so removing it from its superlayer does nothing.

Moreover, this line is pointless:

```
if([subview isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]]){
```

A subview will *never* be a CAShapeLayer. A subview is a UIView. It is not a layer of any kind (though it *has* a layer).

What you *want* to is look for the CAShapeLayers that are *already in the interface*. Of course, an easy way to do this would have been to keep a reference to each CAShapeLayer *at the time you created it and put it into the interface in the first place*:

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:lineShape];
// now store a reference to this layer in an array that you can use later!
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, I'll mark as answered as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: Sometimes we need an outsider to point out the obvious. As soon as I saw your code doesn't make any sense I realized what I did.

Comment: Revised again. You can dispense with the "search" completely if you just keep a reference to each shape layer in your _second_ code, the one that creates the shape layers. You know will need this later so just plan ahead!