# How to remove CAShapeLayer along user drag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

I am new to painting app ,so please suggest me is there any way to remove.

i was googled i am only getting

```
  CGContextSetBlendMode(_context, kCGBlendModeClear);
```

but not for CAShape layer

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingPoint.x,startingPoint.y)];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
//    shapeLayer.strokeColor =kCGBlendModeClear;

    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 7.0;

    }
    else
    {
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0;

    }
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    [clearBeizer addObject:shapeLayer];
```

please help me to remove that layer thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to erase the layer over a user's drag, like an eraser in a painting app?

Comment: @DavidWilliames yes bro..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683480/unable-to-remove-cashapelayer                                  &&    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067578/removing-all-calayers-sublayers

Comment: Okay, a simple approach is rather than actually erasing the shape, is to draw over with the same colour as the background colour. For example, if it is a simple painting app where the background colour is white, the eraser tool could simply paint over with a white colour. I know that doesn't exactly answer your question, but does it solve your problem?

Comment: @DavidWilliames but if user chooses image then it's problem .i have idea while user drag the screen we need to check is there caShapelayer is available or not ,if it is available then we need to remove it.