# How to Remove CAShapelayer along user touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, uitouch, cashapelayer

This is my coding to draw a line using CAShapeLayer .no i like to remove the CAShapeLayer along user drag.

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
                [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)];
                [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingPoint.x,startingPoint.y)];

                shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                shapeLayer.lineCap=kCALineCapSquare;
                shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
                shapeLayer.lineWidth = single.width;
                shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
                [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
                [clearBeizer addObject:shapeLayer];
```

This is screenshot of my expectation:

[image: this is user touched places]

now i like to remove the cashapelayer along user touch like this

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove CAShapeLayer along user drag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053624/how-to-remove-cashapelayer-along-user-drag)

Comment: please don't post multiple questions for the same problem, update the original question with the images and updated code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight way to achieve this. You can try the following ways:

1. Instead of removing the `CAShapeLayer` which is created by a `bezier`-path, you are looking for a way to remove the bezier-path at touch point. One way is to store the bezier points in an `array`, and compare the touch point to the points in an array and remove the point and `redraw` the whole bezier-path with the remaining points.
2. Instead of removing the bezier path, I suggest you to draw a new bezier path with the custom image/path which is having an color similar to the background color of your view, and draw it on the `CAShapeLayer`, so that the bezier path get covered by the new bezier path.